# Php script to convert telugu text from pdf to text file using

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to convert pdf file to text file. PDF file contains Telugu and English language. English words are converting properly, but Telugu is not converting.

I need this to be done using php code.

I have used below code:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('filename.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

But it is working only for English

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.